# Display data in a from using PHP with ODBC

Tags: php, html, sql, odbc

I'm trying to pull data from my DB to a html form, I have managed to so for a table in a while loop, but not for a form. Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){ 
$quote = $_POST['quote'];

}

  $stmt = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblVersions2 WHERE QuoteNumber LIKE '".$quote."'"; 
  $result = odbc_exec($conn, $stmt) or die('ODBC Error: ' . odbc_errormsg($conn) );  


   while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) // while there are rows
  {
    // What do i out here? I only know echo "<td>" . odbc_result($result, "QuoteNumber") . "</td>";
    // which is to display tabular data, but how with a form??
  }

?>
```

I've tried declaring a variable in the while loop, such as $Address1 = -'Address1]; then declaring in the form value=" but it doesn't seem to work, please help!